# default value for chunked field - (setChunked)

Tags: java, vert.x

I am seeing this:

https://vertx.io/docs/kdoc/vertx/io.vertx.rxjava.core.http/-http-server-response/set-chunked.html

```
vertx.createHttpServer()
  .requestHandler(req -> {

    if (req.method() == HttpMethod.GET) {

      req.response().setChunked(true);

    }
 })
```

I would assume chunked is true by default but I can't find the default value in the docs. Does anyone know what the default value is?

Answer (score 2):

`setChunked` sets the `transfer-encoding` header to `chunked`.

When you send some content to the client with the `write` method, Vert.x verifies that either the `transfer-encoding` or the `content-length` header is set.

Answer (score 1):

Do add on the previous answer, you can see the actual code here:

https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/f68ae15171053d343590e54884ec377f095ba6b3/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/http/impl/HttpServerResponseImpl.java#L142

```
public HttpServerResponseImpl setChunked(boolean chunked) {
    synchronized (conn) {
      checkValid();
      // HTTP 1.0 does not support chunking so we ignore this if HTTP 1.0
      if (version != HttpVersion.HTTP_1_0) {
        headers.set(HttpHeaders.TRANSFER_ENCODING, chunked ? "chunked" : null);
      }
      return this;
    }
  }
```